# Haskell exit state monad early (guard?)

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, alternative-functor

I have a type that represents game state for my application, for this question pretend it is something simple like:

```
Game { points :: Int }
```

I define my game logic with the State monad.

```
type GameState a = StateT Game a

addPoints :: Int -> GameState ()
addPoints num = do
    Game p <- get
    put $ Game (p+num)
```

I want to be able to simply discard some inputs

```
evenResult num = do
    Game p <- get
    return $ even (p + num) 

addPoints num = do
    isEven <- evenResult num
    if isEven then return () else do
    Game n <- get
    put $ Game (n+num)
```

I want a syntax that looks something like this

```
addPoints num = do
    guard evenResult
    ...

-- or this
addPoints num = do
    guardIsEvenResult
    ...
```

**If it hits the guard, I want it to leave the state alone, and do nothing else in the block**.

How can I do it? It seems *close* to possible with MonadPlus, but I'm not sure I could use mzero to say "return what you already have in your state". Thanks!

Comment: `StateT` is already a `MonadPlus`. Have you tried just using `Control.Monad.guard`?

Comment: @KevinBallard: `StateT s m` is only a `MonadPlus` if `m` is; the instance just lifts `mzero` and `mplus` one level up.

Comment: Is Control.Monad.when yer man? Granted, it's a nuisance that `when` wants a `Bool` value, rather than a computation that makes a `Bool`. But Rome wasn't burnt in a day. If your `test` lives in `m Bool`, you could write `(test >>=) . flip when $ action` for a tidy kind of perplexity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Import `Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe` and use [`MaybeT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html) on top of `StateT`. Then, you can use [`mzero`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus) to abort the computation or, like Kevin Ballard says, `guard condition` to stop if `condition` is `False`; all you have to do is enclose each block in `runMaybeT`. (Note that you'll either have to `lift` every option you have defined on your `StateT` monad, or change their types to work with any monad with the state you require, like `operation :: (MonadState m Game) => ...`.)

Note that you probably have the `transformers` package that `Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe` is contained in, even if you're not using it directly; the `mtl` package, which contains the standard monad modules like `Control.Monad.State`, depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I'm sort of fleshing out pigworker's comment on the question.

```
ensure :: GameState Bool -> GameState () -> GameState ()
ensure p k = do 
  t <- p 
  when t k

addPoints num = do
  ensure (evenResult num) $ do
  ...
```

Which is close enough. I'm sure ehird's answer is more correct, but it also seems a lot more complicated than I wanted. So much to learn still :)

Comment: Alternatively, I could write ensure as `ensure :: (Game -> Bool) -> GameState () -> GameState ()` and all my predicate functions as `whatever :: Game -> Bool` instead of `whatever :: GameState Bool`